# How to access internet through guest(Virtual OS) Ubuntu with Host Windows 7 behind a Company firewall

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, virtualbox

When I enter a website on the guest OS, it redirects to a webpage where it says to contact the company admin as access was denied. I can access the same website from my host os.

Comment: Possibly some answers [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365104/virtual-machine-can-access-internal-network-but-not-the-internet)

Comment: Thanks @xenoid my company provides a script with a proxy server ip address and port in it. I set that as my guest http proxy setting in the /etc/environment and it did not work. I believe it is something similar to the answer you pointed me to.